# aiohttp and firebase and firebase-admin - is it non blocking? python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, aiohttp, firebase-admin

python 3.6

Here is my firebase code that will check if user exists on firebase:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import auth


cred = credentials.Certificate('wow.json')
default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

def getIsUser(email=None,uid=None):
        try:
            user = auth.get_user(uid)
            is_user = True
        except:
            is_user = False

    return is_user
```

Here is my aiohttp that calls the function:

```
async def jwt_route(request):
    data = await request.json()
    uid = data['uid']
    is_user = getIsUser(uid=uid)

app.router.add_post('/jwt', jwt_route)
```

My question is if the getIsUser(uid=uid) is blocking or not blocking.  If blocking then how do I make it nonblocking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `getIsUser` is a blocking call.

Run it in thread pool: 

`loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
is_user = loop.run_in_executor(None, getIsUser, uid)`

Answer (score 3):

I suggest a different approach from Andrew's answer.
In my opinion - opening threads will complicate the application code and tracking bugs.

Until there is a library that supports `asyncio`, you should use the REST API, calling it asynchronously with `aiohttp`.

For `auth` I am using the database secret which is DEPRECATED, so it's not ideal, but it works for now.